# Is this defined behavior? Store data as char array

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

I was playing with an idea for dynamic size memory pool, and playing, I end up with some code that I was certain that will fail, but didn't. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct largeStruct
{
    largeStruct()
    {
        X = 123456789;
        Y = 987654321;
        str = "Hy! Here I am, a c string, out in the wild c++, the place where your pointers dangle and your friends play with your privates";
    }
    unsigned long long X;
    unsigned long long Y;
    char* str;
};

int main()
{
    void* ptr = new unsigned char[sizeof(largeStruct)];

    largeStruct a;
    *((largeStruct*)ptr) = a;

    cout << "Size of data: " << sizeof(largeStruct) << endl;
    cout << "Data: " << endl;
    cout << ((largeStruct*)ptr)->X << endl
         << ((largeStruct*)ptr)->Y << endl
         << ((largeStruct*)ptr)->str << endl
         << endl;

    delete[] ptr;
}
```

That works in my pc ( Windows 8, MSVC Express 2012). Putting some more though into it, i think that, while a hack, it makes some sense.
A array in memory is like this:

```
===================================
... ||  a0  ||  a1  ||  a2   || ...
===================================
```

So when you try to store a values that is bigger than one of your array members, it access the memory on the side. So try to store a value of 3 chunks size will work, and end up as this:

```
====================================
... || data  data  data  data || ...
====================================
```

So, is this dangerous, or is some kind of obscure harmless hack?

Comment: It "works" on my machine, too. But your code has undefined behaviour, as per C++ standard. You're deleting through `void*` pointer and you're pretending you've got an object of `largeStruct`.

Comment: stick a `std::string` in there and it will cease to "work".

Comment: `largeStruct` has bit-wise copy semantics. That's why it works.

Comment: that's true, a std::string stops this from working. Why is that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> § 3.8 ...any pointer that refers to the storage location where the object will be or was located
>   may be used but only in limited ways... using the pointer as if the pointer were of type void*,
>   is well-defined. Such a pointer may be dereferenced but the resulting lvalue may only be used in limited ways, as described below. The program has undefined behavior if:
>   — the pointer is used as the operand of a static_cast (5.2.9) (except when the conversion is to void*, or to void* and subsequently to char*, or unsigned char*)

and

> § 3.9 The object representation of an object of type T is the sequence of N unsigned char objects taken up by the object of type T, where N equals sizeof(T).

and

> § 3.10/10 If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined:
>   — a char or unsigned char type.

These are very confusing, but seem to call out your pointer bits as legal.  However, you're calling the assignment operator on an object that hasn't been constructed which is illegal.  The best workaround is something like this:

```
std::allocator<largeStruct> al;
largeStruct a;
unsigned char* ptr = new char[sizeof(largeStruct)]; //allocate memory
al.construct((largeStruct*)ptr, a); //call the copy constructor

....

al.destroy((largeStruct*)ptr); //destroy the object
delete[] ptr; //deallocate memory
```

`std::allocator` is the standard allocator used by default by all of the C++ standard containers. `allocate` and `deallocate` simply call `new char[]` and `delete[]` respectively. `construct` constructs the object in place via placement new, and `destroy` destructs it by manually calling the destructor. You can do both yourself in one line of code each, but using allocators is better practice.

Alternatively, instead of constructing a copy of a local instance that was default constructed, simply default construct the `largeStruct` in place with `al.construct((largeStruct*)ptr);`

Comment: Thanks, this was it. Now this: http://pastebin.com/wUL2SY0H works well. Still, I'm unsure of how does std::allocator works. Why does it works with it?

Comment: @SantiagoPacheco: I realized my sample with the allocator was wrong, because I had the wrong type of allocator >.<  It was constructing chars, not a `largeStruct`.  I've fixed my answer.  In your code your never destructing the first `largeStruct` you construct.

Comment: Well, yes, that's correct.  In general you'd want to store the allocator that you use, and then someone can later replace the allocator and change how the memory works.  Normally one would also use the allocator to allocate the memory as well.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The only thing with the second thing you put, is that I want to allocate unknow objects at runtime, so I dont know if i'll ever have a largeStruct, a int, etc.

Comment: Yhea, but a vector has a fixed type. you cant store a int and a string in the same vector.

Comment: @SantiagoPacheco: As long as you keep track of what types are where somehow, you can totally have whatever types you want in the allocated buffer though.  I'm not certain what you perceive the problem to be.

Comment: We are saying the same thing with diferent words :) Anyway, just a toy code, but got me interested for a while. Might expand it to a full garbage collector with memory pool some day.

Comment: @SantiagoPacheco: Memory pools aren't that tricky, but GC turns out to be, because we don't use `T_alloc_type::pointer` and `T_alloc_type::reference` like we're supposed to.